# Understanding mirroring and inverting an object

Tags: modeling, mesh, mirror

When you look in the mirror you see your face flipped left to right. What you don't see is your skin turned inside-out. That would be horrific! Now if we take the gorgeous Suzanne (Monkey) and <kbd>tab</kbd> into Edit Mode, and then enable the Normal direction indicators:

[image]

we see all faces and vertices are facing outward:

[image]

Now, if I chop off half of the mesh, set the Pivot Center to 3D Cursor:

[image][image]

and select all <kbd>A</kbd>. Then duplicate <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and mirror <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> along the X axis, the faces and vertices on the mirrored half are facing inward:

[image]

This could be a programing error, or a bug, or maybe theres a very good reason for it. It can be quite irritating to have to keep flipping the Normals:

[image]

I know that the Mirror Modifier doesn't have this problem, but what about <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, can anyone please enlighten me on this?

Comment: Very interesting, in emulating this, I noticed that if you mirror on the combination of **any** *two* axes the normals don't flip. Tick all 3 and it flips again. -- Also, doing this in *object* mode preserves the normals.

Comment: somewhat related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/how-is-the-normal-direction-determined-when-i-use-make-edge-face

Answer (score 11):

The mirror tool (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) actually inverts the model by scaling it -1. This will flip the model, but will also invert the normals.

Here's what the [docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Deforming/Mirror) say:

> The mirror tool in Edit mode is similar to Mirroring in Object mode.
>   **It is exactly equivalent to scaling by -1 vertices**, edges or faces
>   around one chosen pivot point and in the direction of one chosen axis,
>   only it is faster/handier.

I'm not exactly sure what the mirror modifier is doing, but I'm assuming it copies the vertices location along the axis and puts it in the negative location. Here's what the [docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Mirror) say:

> The Mirror modifier **automatically mirrors a mesh along its local X, Y
>   and/or Z axes**, which pass through the object’s center (the mirror
>   plane is then defined by the two other axes).