# Orthographic camera mirrored in viewport?

Tags: camera, mirror

I'm trying to render a building using an orthographic camera. The first side of the building works fine, but when I mirror the camera to the other side of the building the camera is in the right position but the view through the camera is mirrored on the Y axis.

I tried different things:

1. Mirror the camera again and rotate it around 180°. Doesn't work, the viewport is still mirrored on one axis.
2. Apply Rotation, Location and Scale (doesn't work either)

My question is, how do I fix this behavior?

PS: I fixed it with new camera - but the question, or the answer is still interesting.

Comment: Why do you use mirror ? You should use the 3D cursor (placing it at the building center) to rotate the camera along Z axis, 180°...

Comment: This sounds like it could be a bug. If it is, you could consider [filing a bug report](http://www.blender.org/development/report-a-bug/)

Comment: Related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/mirror-reflection-invertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the [Object mode *Mirror*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Editing#Mirroring_objects) tool works by scaling -1. (the same thing will happen if you manually scale the camera by -1.) You will also notice that in addition to the viewport being mirrored, Object *[Normals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29)* appear reversed.

from the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Deforming/Mirror) about *Edit mode* mirror:

> The mirror tool in Edit mode is similar to [Mirroring in Object mode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Advanced/Mirror).
>   It is exactly equivalent to scaling by -1 vertices, edges or faces
>   around one chosen pivot point and in the direction of one chosen axis,
>   only it is faster/handier.

note that using an Orthographic or Perspective camera does not change this behavior. It is the same on both.

(as already mentioned by Polosson),
The solution is to [Rotate](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Basics/Rotate) the camera instead of mirroring it.

Also as already mentioned by Polosson, one way to do this would be to

1. Select the building, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to selection*
2. Press <kbd>.</kbd> to change the *[Pivot point](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point)* to *[Cursor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/3D_Cursor)*
3. Select the Camera and rotate around the Z axis by 180 degrees. (<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>180</kbd>)